# How to determine in-script if a SQL statement failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am  currently typing a script for a project of mine and currently having difficulties finding information on how to do most of the functionality MS SQL has to offer.

I am trying to figure out a way to test if an SQL statement failed its execution. For example, making an attempt to insert a record that already exists in the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [try/catch capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) of SQL Server.

[Another article source](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3587891/TryCatch-Block-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm) and sample T-SQL:

```
BEGIN TRY
  DECLARE @X INT
  -- Divide by zero to generate Error
  SET @X = 1/0
  PRINT 'Command after error in TRY block'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'Error Detected'
END CATCH
```

E.g. Handle failures in the catch block for specific operations.

Comment: @Steve: No problem. But please don't forget to participate by up/down voting and accepting answers. That's how you validate an answer and that is what makes SO work so well. Please have a look at the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and especially the reputation section. Cheers and Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Try catch is the way to go. If you have many steps in a porcess and want to see details of what it did at some furite date including the errors, you can store the details you need after each step in a table variable as you go (And the error in the catch block) and then after the rollback, insert the details into a permananet logging table. This will give you a history of  errors whch can be invaluable in researching problems later. Table variables do not go out of scope in a rollback while temp tables would.